# junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: TextView contains correct text

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

I have simple robolectric class where I check the String value of my textView. The test simply checks that our TextView exists and has the text "Hello World!"

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest {
private MainActivity activity;


@Test
public void validateTextViewContent() {
    activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
    TextView tvHelloWorld = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.tvHelloWorld);

    assertNotNull("TextView could not be found", tvHelloWorld);
    assertTrue("TextView contains correct text",
            "Hello world!".equals(tvHelloWorld.getText().toString()));
  }
}
```

When I run it though,I get the following error.

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: TextView contains correct text

at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:57)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:22)
at testing.theo.androidtextviewrobo.MainActivityTest.validateTextViewContent(MainActivityTest.java:29)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:251)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: First thing is that you may use assertEquals in place of assertTrue. But I assume that might not help you.

Comment: No it doesn't work either with assertEquals.:(

Comment: Try adding just some text to that TextView before asserting.
tvHelloWorld.setText("");

Comment: Post your xml layout, post your `onCreate()` method

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed!!!I removed the assertTrue and added this line

```
assertEquals(tvHelloWorld.getText().toString(), "Hello World!");
```